# Large image with clickable sections

Tags: android

I've an large image in my android app, which represents a real pictured device.
Now I would like to know, whats the best way to do the following:

- Mark some specific image sectors as clickable
- Visual preview the click event (like a normal android button)

I've thought about something like the "imagemap" similar solution of
http://catchthecows.com/?p=113.
But it doesn't highlight the clicked section (neccessary for me).
It's not possible, or lets say very complicated, to create "n" different pictures which handle the highlighting effect (for example: section 1 clicked - so highlighting it, section 2 clicked - so higlighting it ....).

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks a lot.

Btw:
My image looks like the following (the red sections should be clickable).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had quick look at the `ImageMap` source you provided.

Here's the `onDraw()` method for `ImageMap`:

```
/**
* Paint the view
* image first, location decorations next, bubbles on top
*/
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    drawMap(canvas);
    drawLocations(canvas);
    drawBubbles(canvas);
}
```

So, as the comment states, the full image is drawn first, followed by the 'location decorations' (which would seem to be an area of particular interest), and finally the area 'bubbles', which basically seem to be tooltips for the selectable areas and might not be applicable to you.

Taking a look at the drawing method for the 'location decorations':

```
protected void drawLocations(Canvas canvas) {
    for (Area a : mAreaList) {
        a.onDraw(canvas);
    }   
}
```

And finally the draw method for the `Area` objects (which are the definable, selectable image areas):

```
// an onDraw is set up to provide an extensible way to
// decorate an area. When drawing remember to take the
// scaling and translation into account
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (_decoration != null) {
        float x = (getOriginX() * mResizeFactorX) + mScrollLeft - 17;
        float y = (getOriginY() * mResizeFactorY) + mScrollTop - 17;
        canvas.drawBitmap(_decoration, x, y, null);
    }
}
```

I would say your best bet would be to use the `ImageMap` class to take care of most of the required functionality. You can use the supplied `Area.onDraw()` method to take care of the area 'highlighting'. Instead of drawing a 'decoration bitmap', use the shape information defined in the `Area` class or subclasses and use `Canvas` methods to draw a transparent highlight mask over the selected areas.

EDIT: You would need a seperate `onDraw()` implementation for each of the `Area` subclasses, as the area bounds information is stored in the subclasses.

Comment: Thank you Tyler.
I've changed the bubble class (onDraw Method) to match my needs.